# Fully lost all documents after clearing trash

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave

My friend lost all her documents, downloads, and desktop files. The thing is that she lost the entire folders. When I go into her users there are shortcuts to the desktop, download and documents folders, but they do not go anywhere. She emptied her trash bin and she thought it was 3 files in it, but she saw 1500 files being deleted. I think she accidently moved her 3 folders into the trash, and was just using the shortcut in the users to access them.

I tried using a disk recovery software but no files could be found. I think the index of documents has been deleted, but the files are still there. Time machine was not enabled, and icloud was not either.

I'm kind of hoping for a special case where you can recover permanently deleted folders if their documents or desktop

Answer (score 1):

The thing with deleting files (unless you specifically do a "secure erase") is that the files are still there. What happens (over simplification warning here) is that the part of the disk on which the deleted files reside is marked as "free." In other words as you use the computer, save files, move things around it is possible and even likely that that space will be used and the deleted files well and truly wiped out by being replaced by the new file.

It's like you parked your car at the mall and then lost it. It's still there you just don't know where it is and if you leave it there long enough it will get towed.

There are Mac utilities that purport to recover accidentally deleted files. I couldn't tell you how well they work and which are the worth the $$ you pay for the software and which are not. But I would imagine a quick online search for an "un-delete" or "file recovery" software for macOS would yield recommendations.

The thing to remember is that the more you use the Mac with the deleted files the less likely that you will be able to recover anything.

And one more thing. There are companies that specialize in recovering lost data. Such services can be *very* expensive. It all depends on how much the lost data is worth.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said Time Machine wasn't enabled, but with modern macOS using the APFS file system, Time Machine may be using APFS local snapshots. See [About Time Machine local snapshots](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204015).

I know you said said iCloud Drive wasn't enabled, but I have seen instances where iCloud Drive was unknowingly enabled, and macOS moved the Desktop and Documents folders to `~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/` without creating the proper Finder Aliases to have them show up correctly in Finder. Use Terminal to check the contents of that folder.

Comment: RE: "I know you said Time Machine wasn't enabled, but with modern macOS using the APFS file system, Time Machine may be using APFS local snapshots. " --  As the OP stated "Time machine was not enabled, and icloud was not either.", then no _local snapshots_ would have been created, that is unless things have changed. In other words, it's my understanding that _local snapshots_ are not created unless **Time Machine** is enabled.